# Error with RelativeLayout and EditText

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, android-relativelayout

I am trying to add ads into my app, and I get this weird error that I just can't see how I am possibly getting it. Here is the error

```
  05-30 20:02:48.889: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3420): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-30 20:02:48.889: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3420): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{coderaustin.com/coderaustin.com.Main}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.EditText
05-30 20:02:48.889: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3420):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
05-30 20:02:48.889: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3420):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
05-30 20:02:48.889: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3420):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
05-30 20:02:48.889: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3420):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
05-30 20:02:48.889: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3420):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-30 20:02:48.889: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3420):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-30 20:02:48.889: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3420):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
05-30 20:02:48.889: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3420):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-30 20:02:48.889: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3420):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
05-30 20:02:48.889: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3420):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
05-30 20:02:48.889: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3420):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
05-30 20:02:48.889: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3420):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-30 20:02:48.889: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3420): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.EditText
05-30 20:02:48.889: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3420):     at coderaustin.com.Main.onCreate(Main.java:79)
05-30 20:02:48.889: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3420):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
05-30 20:02:48.889: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3420):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
05-30 20:02:48.889: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3420):     ... 11 more
```

As you can see, it's somehow getting an instance of EditText out of this code

```
 AdView adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, "my pub code");
    View view = findViewById(R.id.RelLayout);
    if(view instanceof RelativeLayout) {
        Log.e("It's layout", "fixed");
    } else {
        Log.e("NOOOO", "Instance of: " + view.getClass().getName());

    }
   **RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.RelLayout);**
   layout.addView(adView);

   adView.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM);
    // Add the adView to it

    // Initiate a generic request to load it with an ad
    adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());
```

Maybe it's something obvious and I am just oblivious to it, I just don't see where I'm going wrong. Thanks for all help.

Edit: Just incase you wanted to see my layout, here it is

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:id="@+id/RelLayout"
>
```

Comment: Can you post your layout? And which is Line 79?

Comment: @user775598 I added the part with relativelayout, and the line with the ** around it is line 79.

Comment: Is there any chance at all that you have an EditText with the same ID? Other than that, I have no clue.

Comment: @user775598 I really don't see how I could, but here are my two EditText's in the layout, `code <EditText android:text=""
    android:password="true"
     android:id="@+id/EditText01"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"></EditText>
       
        <EditText android:text=""
    android:password="true"
     android:id="@+id/EditText02"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/EditText01" /> `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing I can think of is that your project properties (which includes IDs) need fixing. They get out of sync sometimes when you add new IDs/other properties to the project. In eclipse you can right click on the project and select Android > Fix Project Properties. If that doesn't work I have sometimes had to delete all of my .class files (including R.class) and re-compile.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, I tried that before and it didn't work, but it seemed to work this time, weird. Thanks again.

Comment: Yeah the 'Fix Project Properties' thing has been unreliable for me (hence the full re-build at times).

Comment: I've found that when I modify any xml file lately, I have to use eclipses "Clean Project" for the resources in the apk to be properly updated. This is equivalent to deleting the class files as @Gary mentions.